# How to get siblings by text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to figure out how to get a sibling element by text. This is what I currently have:

```
var elem = $('div');
var e = elem.siblings('.condition').contains('text');
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it based on a sibling text. I don't want to traverse the whole DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has no `contains()` method which works as you expect it to. Instead you need to use the `:contains` selector. Try this:

```
var $elem = $('div');
var $e = elem.siblings('.condition:contains("text")');
console.log($e.length); // will be greater than 0 if an element was matched
```

You can also concatenate a variable in the selector if required:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var $e = $elem.siblings('.condition:contains("' + foo + '")');
```

And as suggested by @DavidThomas you could use `filter()`:

```
var $e = $elem.siblings().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'text';
});
```

Comment: Actually, JQuery does have a [.contains()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method, it just doesn't do what the OP wants it to do :)

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, added that as a possible alternative

Answer (score 2):

the [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector should do everything you need:

```
var elem = $('div');
elem.siblings(".condition:contains('text')");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('div').siblings(':contains("text here")');`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obodJB

Answer (score 1):

As you posted this question with both JavaScript and jQuery tags, I thought I'd take the time to offer a JavaScript solution (although you've already accepted a jQuery solution). Bearing in mind this is currently restricted, realistically, to those browsers incorporating ECMAScript 6:

```
// 'start' : Node, NodeList, HTMLCollection, Array of Nodes
//           The nodes whose siblings you're searching for
// 'needle': String, the text-content you're looking to select
//           sibling nodes by.

function getSiblingsByTextContent(start, needle) {

  // converting the supplied start variable into an Array:
  var allStarts = Array.from(start),

  // Using the spread operator ('...') to create a new Set
  // of the unique array elements from the new array
  // formed from Array.prototype.map(); here we use
  // an Array function to return the parentNode of n (the
  // node from the allStarts Array):
    uniqueParents = [...new Set(allStarts.map(n => n.parentNode))],

    // here we iterate over the uniqueParents Array, and form
    // a new Array, using Array.prototype.map() again:
    allSiblings = uniqueParents.map(function(n) {
    // n is the current array-element from the array
    // over which we're iterating.

    // converting the children of the node, using
    // Array.prototype.filter():
      return Array.from(n.children).filter(function(nc) {
      // here we keep only those nodes (here 'nc') that
      // are not contained within the AllStarts array, and
      // whose textContent contains the needle we're searching for:
        return allStarts.indexOf(nc) === -1 && nc.textContent.match(needle);
      });
      // we reduce the returned array of arrays, with
      // Array.prototype.reduce, combining each Array
      // element with the array that precedes it,
      // intialising with an Array literal ('[]')
    }).reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b), []);

    // and returning the found-siblings to the calling
    // context:
  return allSiblings;
}

// calling the named function, suppling a NodeList of
// span elements found in the document, searching for
// siblings containing the '-' character:
getSiblingsByTextContent(document.querySelectorAll('span'), '4')
// as the function returns an Array we can iterate over that
// Array using Array.prototype.forEach() to add a new
// class to each element's classList to show the found-
// siblings:
.forEach(n => n.classList.add('found'));
```

```js
// 'start' : Node, NodeList, HTMLCollection, Array of Nodes
//           The nodes whose siblings you're searching for
// 'needle': String, the text-content you're looking to select
//           sibling nodes by.

function getSiblingsByTextContent(start, needle) {

  // converting the supplied start variable into an Array:
  var allStarts = Array.from(start),

    // Using the spread operator ('...') to create a new Set
    // of the unique array elements from the new array
    // formed from Array.prototype.map(); here we use
    // an Array function to return the parentNode of n (the
    // node from the allStarts Array):
    uniqueParents = [...new Set(allStarts.map(n => n.parentNode))],

    // here we iterate over the uniqueParents Array, and form
    // a new Array, using Array.prototype.map() again:
    allSiblings = uniqueParents.map(function(n) {
      // n is the current array-element from the array
      // over which we're iterating.

      // converting the children of the node, using
      // Array.prototype.filter():
      return Array.from(n.children).filter(function(nc) {
        // here we keep only those nodes (here 'nc') that
        // are not contained within the AllStarts array, and
        // whose textContent contains the needle we're searching for:
        return allStarts.indexOf(nc) === -1 && nc.textContent.match(needle);
      });
      // we reduce the returned array of arrays, with
      // Array.prototype.reduce, combining each Array
      // element with the array that precedes it,
      // intialising with an Array literal ('[]')
    }).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);

  // and returning the found-siblings to the calling
  // context:
  return allSiblings;
}

// calling the named function, suppling a NodeList of
// span elements found in the document, searching for
// siblings containing the '-' character:
getSiblingsByTextContent(document.querySelectorAll('span'), '4')
  // as the function returns an Array we can iterate over that
  // Array using Array.prototype.forEach() to add a new
  // class to each element's classList to show the found-
  // siblings:
  .forEach(n => n.classList.add('found'));
```

```css
div div::before,
div span::before {
  content: '( ';
}
div div::after,
div span::after {
  content: ' )';
}
.found {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1 - span</span>
  <span>2 - span</span>
  <span>3 - span</span>
  <div>4 - div</div>
  <span>5 - span</span>
  <span>6 - span</span>
  <span>7 - span</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>8 - span</span>
  <span>9 - span</span>
  <span>10 - span</span>
  <div>11 - div</div>
  <span>12 - span</span>
  <span>13 - span</span>
  <span>14 - span</span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nb074e76/1/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children).
- [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
- [Spread Operator (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Match).